# How to setup .htaccess to show 404 for unallowed urls?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I noticed in Drupal if you add .php to the url bar of any page it gives you a 404 message; clean urls enabled.  The page is obviously a .php, but the .htaccess is preventing the user from being able to tamper with url extensions in the url bar.  How could you do this using .htaccess.  I have file extensions omitted at the moment, but would also like to add that feature.  Thank you.

Also, this question does not pertain to Drupal.  I only mentioned Drupal for and example.

Comment: I will rephrase: How to prevent users from writing not-existing URLs? And you know answer.

Comment: @OZ_ reading question body usually helps to understand the question.

Comment: Drupal URLs do not point to physical PHP files, they are virtual URLs redirected to an `index.php` which handles the request. Hence adding `.php` to the URL will give 404 because that URL simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel so smart idea! However, there is no way for `preventing the user from being able to tamper with url extensions in the url bar` (from body of question). User can write in URL anything he wants.

Comment: Could you please explain that in more depth.  How can it redirect content into an existing page?  Is that common practice / typical way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

Just because a file contains PHP code it doesn't mean it has to have the `.php` extension; even more so when you're accessing a file over the internet.

When you request http://mysite.com/page and you're using an `.htaccess` like Drupal's, the request is forwarded onto `index.php?q=page` whereupon Drupal will check it's database for a path matching `page`. If it finds one it will display the content for that page, if not it will (rightly) give a 404.

If you want all of your pages to be accessible with a PHP extension you could add an extra rule in your `.htaccess` file to remove `.php` from any request where the PHP file doesn't physically exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1 [NC]
```

Bear in mind though that this adds zero extra value for your site's visitors (in fact they have to remember a file extension as well as the path to the page), and it exposes exactly what server-side technology you're using so a potential attacker would have some of his work done for him.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please explain that in more depth. How can it redirect content into an existing page? Is that common practice / typical way of doing things?

Yes it is a very common practice, used by most frameworks and CMS.

The principle is simple: you setup your `.htaccess` so that every request which doesn't match a real file or directory will be redirected to a front controller, usually the `index.php` in the root directory of the application. That front controller handles the request by analyzing the URL and calling the necessary actions.

In this way you can minimize the rewrite rules to just one, and you can offer customized 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno Drupal but in the usual php app every request being routed to the front controller which performs some validations and throws 404 on errors.
easy-peasy